# Sort a string item statement

Tags: vb.net

Can I do this shorter from a single timer without needing 5 timers?

I can run it in a sub `Timer1.Enabled = True`, `Timer1.Start ()` and can change according to preferences, `timer2`, `timer3`. so I want to do this to go shorter. I think I should have a case function, or something like that. how could i do it

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim strx As String
        Dim stry As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            strx = TextBox1.Lines(i)
            stry = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text
            If stry.Contains(strx) = True Then
                Exit For
                RndTitaniumA1()
            Else
                Exit For
                If TextBox4.Text = ("1") Then
                    BttRnd.PerformClick()
                Else
                    RndTitaniumA2()
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Timer1.Stop()
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Dim strx As String
        Dim stry As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            strx = TextBox1.Lines(i)
            stry = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text
            If stry.Contains(strx) = True Then
                Exit For
                RndTitaniumA1()
            Else
                Exit For
                If TextBox4.Text = ("2") Then
                    BttRnd.PerformClick()
                Else
                    RndTitaniumA3()
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Timer2.Stop()
        Timer2.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        Dim strx As String
        Dim stry As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            strx = TextBox1.Lines(i)
            stry = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text
            If stry.Contains(strx) = True Then
                Exit For
                RndTitaniumA1()
            Else
                Exit For
                If TextBox4.Text = ("3") Then
                    BttRnd.PerformClick()
                Else
                    RndTitaniumA4()
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Timer3.Stop()
        Timer3.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
        Dim strx As String
        Dim stry As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            strx = TextBox1.Lines(i)
            stry = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text
            If stry.Contains(strx) = True Then
                Exit For
                RndTitaniumA1()
            Else
                Exit For
                If TextBox4.Text = ("4") Then
                    BttRnd.PerformClick()
                Else
                    RndTitaniumA5()
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Timer4.Stop()
        Timer4.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer5_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer5.Tick
        Dim strx As String
        Dim stry As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            strx = TextBox1.Lines(i)
            stry = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text
            If stry.Contains(strx) = True Then
                Exit For
                RndTitaniumA1()
            Else
                Exit For
                If TextBox4.Text = ("5") Then
                    BttRnd.PerformClick()
                Else
                    MsgBox("")
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Timer5.Stop()
        Timer5.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does this code work as written? If not does it have any errors? What and what line? Does it produce the expected results? If not how do the results differ from your expected results?

Comment: What is the point of the For loop if you are going to exit it after the first iteration?

Comment: `RndTitaniumA1()` and `If TextBox4.Text = ("5") Then
                    BttRnd.PerformClick()
                Else
                    MsgBox("")
                End If` will never run.

Comment: Why are you showing an empty message box?

Comment: Are you intentionally skipping the first line in TextBox1? How are you absolutely sure that the text box has 10 or 11 lines? A user can change the contents of a text box.

Comment: I don't know about reducing the number of Timers. Why do you have 5? Are they all set a different intervals?

Comment: I don't understand your title at all. I don't see any Sort or Items.

Comment: You can try assigning all the timer tick events to the same handler then maybe cast sender to a Timer .... And the above questions asked by @Mary needs answers.

Comment: everything is done automatically, the first line will always start from 1, and in the textbox there will always be at least 10 lines written. each timer will contain something else, as shown above, something changes to them.

Comment: why won't it run? RndTitaniumA1 () and If TextBox4.Text = ("5") Then BttRnd.PerformClick () Else MsgBox ("") End If - and how can I make it run?

Comment: the moment the stry contains on, then something else happens. When it does not exist, then something else will happen. should the code above do this, or does it?

Comment: if you want to tell me how to work RndTitaniumA1, if you told me it doesn't work.

Comment: Minor grammatical changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your answers to my questions.

Array indexes in .net start at zero. If you have 10 lines in your textbox, you will get an index out of range exception with `For i As Integer = 1 To 10` because there is no index 10. The indexes run from 0 to 9. I still don't see how you are preventing the user from deleting a few lines.

It won't run because you have preceded the code with `Exit For`. When the code reaches that line it exits the For loop and goes immediately to `TimerX.Stop()`.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    For i = 0 To 10
        Exit For
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

The `MessageBox` in the above code will never be displayed. Even if you repositioned the `Exit For`, you have the exit in both the `If` block and the `Else` block so the code would only survive one iteration.

You still didn't answer if the code works as written or why you are using a `For` loop at all and leaving the loop on the first iteration. Also, the mysterious empty `MsgBox` and why there are 5 timers.

You can add a break point and step through your code.

Notice the `Handles` clause in the `.Tick` event. This event now handles all the Timers.

I used a `Select Case` as suggested by @preciousbetine in comments. Since a `Timer` is a component it has no `Name` property (what I would normally use in the `Select Case`) so, I used the `Is` operator. I could also have set the `.Tag` property for each Timer and used that. I left in the `Exit For` (repositioned) but be aware; you will only get a single iteration.

Calling an event in code can have unanticipated effects. I showed you how to move the code from the button click to a separate `Sub` and then call it from the `.Click` and your routine.

```
Private Sub AnyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick, Timer2.Tick, Timer3.Tick, Timer4.Tick, Timer5.Tick
    Dim t As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer)
    Dim strx As String
    Dim stry As String

    stry = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        strx = TextBox1.Lines(i)
        If stry.Contains(strx) = True Then
            RndTitaniumA1()
            Exit For
        Else
            Dim TextBox4Contents As String = ""
            Select Case True
                Case t Is Timer1
                    TextBox4Contents = "1"
                Case t Is Timer2
                    TextBox4Contents = "2"
                Case t Is Timer3
                    TextBox4Contents = "3"
                Case t Is Timer4
                    TextBox4Contents = "4"
                Case t Is Timer5
                    TextBox4Contents = "5"
            End Select
            If TextBox4.Text = TextBox4Contents Then
                RndSub()
            Else
                Select Case True
                    Case t Is Timer1
                        RndTitaniumA2()
                    Case t Is Timer2
                        RndTitaniumA3()
                    Case t Is Timer3
                        RndTitaniumA4()
                    Case t Is Timer4
                        RndTitaniumA5()
                    Case t Is Timer5
                        MsgBox("") '???
                    Case Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Sender does not match any Timer")
                        Return
                End Select

            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    t.Stop()
    t.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub BttnRnd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttnRnd.Click
    RndSub()
End Sub

Private Sub RndSub()
    'Your button code here
End Sub
```

Comment: how should i refer to textbox2, 3 to 5? I'm not very successful. timer2.start, timer2.enabled=true not worked :( object not found.